# web.xml <error-page>が機能しない

Tags: java, tomcat, servlet

現在下記のような実装になっております↓

```html
tomcat8

～java
public class FRGW010S_DispAction extends HttpServlet{
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)throws       
  ServletException,IOException{
    try{
        new FileInputStream("nofile.txt");
    catch(IOException  e){
        throw new ServletException(e);
～
～web.xml
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
～
```

エラーをthrowすることで、error.jspに遷移して欲しいのですが、実行すると画面は真っ白で、コンソールには

```html
java.io.FileNotFoundException: nofile.txt (指定されたファイルが見つかりません。)・・・
```

と出力されているだけです。

原因が掴めないのですが、error-page自体が起動していないように思います(servlet-mapping等は機能している)。error-pageタグ内のexception-typeを省略し、エラーを発生させても動作しないことから、起動時にerror-pageを読み込めていないのではないかと思い調査中です。
また、記述は間違えていないと思うので、おそらく些細な原因なのではないかと考えています。

error.jspに遷移しない原因の分かる方がいましたら、ご教授をお願いします。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

error-pageの指定が無ければ、
そもそもデフォルトのエラーページで例外表示されるはずですので、
error-pageの設定自体が読めていないから白い画面になっているのでは
ないと考えられます。

そもそもExceptionがどこかでcatchされていて、伝搬していないということはありませんか？
error-pageのタグごと削除したらデフォルトのエラーページは表示されますか？

Comment: >そもそもExceptionがどこかでcatchされていて
これが原因でした。catchで握りつぶされている部分を見落としていました。
上記を改善したところ、error-pageが動作しました。

どうもありがとうございます。